# How to define separate file for all acronyms in latex?

Tags: compilation, latex, acronym

Currently I am defining acronys at the start of each chapter. I want to make a separate file for all acronyms.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}
\end{document}
```

```
\chapter{ch1}
\acrfull{WLAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem

\newacronym{WLAN}{WLAN}{Wireless Local Area Network}
```

```
\chapter{ch2}
\acrfull{LAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem

\newacronym{LAN}{LAN}{Local Area Network}
```

How can I make all the acronyms in a separate file lets say acronyms.tex? And how to call them in the main file?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: is there any other community you are available on? I wanted to ask another question but I am unable to post the question.

Comment: You should be able to ask again if you wait a bit.

Comment: Yes Watching my clock tick tock :p

Comment: You could use the time to add the missing `\ ` in front of `end{document}` to your questions from today or add the missing [mre] to yesterday's question :)

Comment: You are already kind enough to edit my questions how could you miss adding '/' to the end{document} :p. and I seriously don't have any idea about yesterday question because I don't have any clue where the problem is. And thanks for the help always :)

Comment: Editing other people's code is frowned upon. We can't know if this is just a typo in your question or if it might be in your real document.

Comment: And for your question yesterday: you don't need to have a clue where the error is because you do have the document. Make a copy and then keep removing stuff as long as the error is still there. This should give you a [mre].

Comment: regarding yesterday's question, I solved that by making a completely new document from scratch. I copied and pasted everything and it solved the problem of citation. Next time ill try to make a minimal reproducible example as you advised.

Answer (score 3):

You can have them in a separate file like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\input{acronyms}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\chapter{ch1}
\acrfull{WLAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem

\chapter{ch2}
\acrfull{LAN} is used as a trial for my example and problem

\end{document}
```

with `acronyms.tex`:

```
\newacronym{WLAN}{WLAN}{Wireless Local Area Network}
\newacronym{LAN}{LAN}{Local Area Network}
```